# Configure Rest on IBM MQ Local Installation

Tags: ibm-mq

I have installed a IBM MQ Developer version on a server, and I need to configure Rest requests, to be more specific it must be able to put message in the queue using a Rest request.

Unfortunately I didn't find any good source of information about this...

Comment: What bad information did you find?

Comment: This getting started with REST page should be useful - https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_9.1.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q130950_.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run the MQ web server. Use the command `strmqweb`.

See https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_9.1.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.adm.doc/q127860_.html